# Conditional formatting formula involving max date in a row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple dates in a row.  I set up a CF formula to highlight dates greater than today.  I need help setting up another CF formula that will highlight the max date in the row less than today.  So for example, if today is `2/18/2019` and I have rows with the following dates...

```
2/15/2019 | 2/16/2019 | 2/17/2019
```

I want `2/17/2019` to highlight.

```
=A7=max($A7:$M7)<Today
```

Answer (score 0):

Please select Row7 and apply a CF formula rule of:

```
=A7=min(max(7:7),today()-1)
```

Comment: I attempted your formula; however, not getting any results.  Can you take a look at this spreadsheet and let me know what I did wrong?     https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXsJaSftxAYOfmkPaj-2XXeHPoQWklpqfLpmPmYUKh8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAX(FILTER($A24:24, $A24:24<TODAY()))
```

[image: 1]